# Alguem pode me ajudar? Eu quero saber como faz para ter um looping while que não deixe prosseguir até a resposta estar correta

Tags: java

Eu estou estudando programação sozinho e sou bem iniciante na programação de jogos e estou tentando fazer um mini joguinho de texto tipo um rpg de mesa onde o console faz uma pergunta ao jogador e o jogador responde a pergunta (exemplo se o jogador quer ir pra frente ou os lados), porém, eu não estou conseguindo fazer um looping que faz com que sempre que o jogador não escolha uma das opções, escreva sempre uma mensagem falando para ele escolher as opções certas e pedindo uma resposta no console, no meu código apenas pergunta uma vez e apenas deixa o jogador coloque a resposta uma vez e mesmo se a resposta esteja correta ou não ele finaliza o código e eu queria que sempre perguntasse para o jogador e sempre deixasse ele responder sem terminar até responder corretamente e prosseguir o código.

Meu código(está na IDE do Eclipse utilizando Java):

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();
    String nome;
    System.out.println("Seja bem-vindo ao jogo! Por favor insira seu nome:");
    nome = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Seja muito bem-vindo(a) " + nome);
    System.out.println("Você deseja avançar para qual direção?(w,a,s,d)");
    String comando = in.nextLine();
    
    if(comando.equals("w")) {
        System.out.println("Você avançou para frente");
        System.out.println("Surgiu um Inimigo! O que você deseja fazer?(a = atacar f = fugir)");
        comando = in.nextLine();
        while(!comando.equals("a") || !comando.equals("f")) {
            System.out.println("Escolha apenas as opções a ou f");
            comando = in.nextLine();
            return;}
            if(comando.equals("a")) {
                System.out.println("Você atacou o inimigo e o matou");
            }
            else if(comando.equals("f")) {
                System.out.println("Você foi um covarde e fugiu! ");
            }
    }
```

obs: Eu não coloquei outros códigos para o a,s,d porque estava testando primeiro com o w

Answer (score -4):

Segue o código que executa conforme o esperado.
O ***return*** sai do ***while*** e não executa nenhum código abaixo dele saindo da função.
O seu ***while*** mesmo digitando `"a"` por exemplo continua o loop porque a segunda condição ainda é satisfeita `!comando.equals("f")`.
Deixei os pontos anteriores comentados.

Como você esta começando a programação vai ser difícil, não desista, procure olhar o ponto que seu código falha e tente responder o por que ? Se você identificar uma tarefa específica procure na internet como resolver essa tarefa. No seu caso erra procurar um item em um Array de String.

```java
import java.util.*;

class Help {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        String nome;
        System.out.println("Seja bem-vindo ao jogo! Por favor insira seu nome:");
        nome = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Seja muito bem-vindo(a) " + nome);
        System.out.println("Você deseja avançar para qual direção?(w,a,s,d)");
        String comando = in.nextLine();
        String [] optionsAF = { "a", "f" };
        
        if(comando.equals("w")) {
            System.out.println("Você avançou para frente");
            System.out.println("Surgiu um Inimigo! O que você deseja fazer?(a = atacar f = fugir)");
            comando = in.nextLine();
             //while(!comando.equals("a") || !comando.equals("f")) {
            // conforme a documentação [Arrays.binarySearch()][1] vai retornar um int >= 0 se achar o elemento
            while(Arrays.binarySearch(optionsAF, comando) < 0) {
                System.out.println("Escolha apenas as opções a ou f");
                comando = in.nextLine();
                // return; // nao deixa executar os codigo a baixo, saindo da função autal
            }
            if(comando.equals("a")) {
                System.out.println("Você atacou o inimigo e o matou");
            }
            else if(comando.equals("f")) {
                System.out.println("Você foi um covarde e fugiu! ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```